# Star Alliance programme with free expiry date extension

Tags: loyalty-programs, star-alliance

I'm currently enrolled at Victoria (by TAP). Even though I collected new miles over the holidays, my old miles will expire.

**What other Star Alliance programme would extend the expiry date of all my miles without extra charges?**

Note that this is the case with FlyingBlue (by KLM): my miles would expire in February, but with the new miles I collected over the holidays, **all** my miles have a new expiry date. Thanks.

**EDIT:** [This list](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/milesbuzz/1706167-miles-points-do-don-t-expire.html) shows a number of airlines that allow free resetting of expiry date, although it doesn't split the airlines by alliance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the programs are independent. Earning miles goes to one program and that program sets its own expiry date policy. To postpone expiry (which is possible with every reward program I know but it might not be the case for all) you must have activity in *the account* whose miles are about to expire.

Any activity will do, so you can fly with another Star Alliance member and have them credit the miles to the account you want to postpone expiry. Also, flights are not necessarily needed, you can spend with a partner which are numerous (flower shops, hotels, cars, etc, depending on the program). The point though is that the activity has to be in that account, not any other one, even if it is with Star Alliance.

**Addendum:**

Victoria has a set expiry after 3 years of arcual which can  be extended for a charge. Many other Star Alliance programs though, such as Aeroplan by AirCanada and Mileage Plus by United Airlines, do not have a set expiry but the whole lot of miles gets its expiry pushed forward when there is activity in the account. These are distinct programs from Victoria and so getting any of these will not prevent current Victoria miles from expiring.

Comment: Thanks Itai, but my Victoria account clearly says that a fraction of my miles are expiring, even though there was new activity last month.

Comment: @Rodrigo - Ah, OK. In that case, those are miles you accumulated 3+ years ago, I believe that is the set limit for the lifetime of Victoria miles and you must pay to extend them using [this tool](https://www.flytap.com/en-at/victoria/extend-miles).

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking of a cost-free extension. I will edit my question to highlight this.

Comment: Several other StarAlliance (Aeroplan and United to name the two I know) program will do it but none will impact your Victoria miles. They will only keep pushing the expiry date of the miles earned in their program.

Comment: There is another bit of magic and that is having a partner credit card. While your account is in good standing, miles in the associated program just do not expire, at least that is how it works with the Aeroplan visa card. No idea if there is one for Victoria though.

Comment: Yeah, at this stage I am not trying to salvage the TAP miles but to start an account somewhere else, with fairer terms (I find it unfair to pay extra to reset the expiry date). I thought of getting a Miles&More credit card, which removes the expiry date from Miles&More miles, but it seems this card is no longer available where I live (UK). I've seen that MileagePlus (by United Airlines) resets the clock for miles like FlyingBlue does, but I've never flown with them; would you advise against signing up with MP in my case, or does it not matter that I don't fly with them?

Comment: BTW I found this website, with a good list of mile programmes that reset the clock for free (or never expire miles!): https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/milesbuzz/1706167-miles-points-do-don-t-expire.html It almost answers my question, but it does not say which airlines are Star Alliance. I'll do that manual investigation myself...

Comment: That is fine. I had several accounts with airlines I never flew with. In the end though I consolidated under one per alliance to reduce the number of forced transactions just to update expiry. I would look at the redemption plans to decide which one is best for you, some are better depending on your flying habits (where , how often and  how much in advance you book).

Answer (score 0):

I know that Lufthansa had that same principle (‘each mile is lost after 18 month, no matter how often you fly’). I changed for that reason to the United program (even though I fly mostly Lufthansa), which allows a refresh of all existing miles by any flight.

[I have been told that Lufthansa now changed that]